# Using an NSDictionary with Arrays to populate UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

First please forgive if the title isn't correct terminology. I've searched and searched the questions here and I'm not finding a relevant solution do to the format of my plist. I'm trying to implement the following code and maybe I'm going about it wrong.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"master" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
self.spots = [dict objectForKey:@"Rooms"];
```

This is the format of my plist and ideally I'd like to pull all "Rooms" into a table from this list.

```
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
   <key>Rooms</key>
   <dict>
     <key>Basement</key>
     <array>
       <string>Stereo</string>
       <string>TV</string>
     </array>
     <key>Bathroom</key>
     <array>
       <string>Lights</string>
     </array>
     <key>BedRoom 1</key>
     <array>
       <string>Blinds</string>
       <string>Lights</string>
       <string>Stereo</string>
       <string>TV</string>
     </array>
```

I've tried using `[dict allKeys]` which resulted in an unsorted result only after I changed the format of my plist. My problem should be obvious, I can't get past the "Rooms" key and list the keys nested in the dictionary. What's wrong here? My code? My plist? I've read for hours and I'd like to see a relevant example that I'll be able to pull apart and learn or explanation in plain English if someone feels like just posting a link or saying just use.....

Comment: Print your dict in NSLog. EX : NSLog(@"dict :%@", dict); And past the log details.

Comment: @Natarajan Sorry I don't have the luxury of IB or a Mac. I'm using THEOS to create my app

Comment: According to the page at http://iphonedevwiki.net, "Theos also includes Logify, which accepts a class header and generates a MobileSubstrate extension which hooks all of that class's methods, printing log messages when they are called. This helps a hook developer see when certain methods are invoked during use."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at your code, `self.spots` should be a dictionary of rooms. I think you are asking how do you then get an ordered list of keys so you can present them alphabetically?

```
NSArray * sortedKeys = [[self.spots allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

You can then use the sorted keys to access the Dictionaries in the correct order

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've updated the wording for conversations sake. The problem lies at `[dict objectForKey:@"Rooms"]` returns no objects. To `[dict allKeys]` I had to rearrange my data structure which isn't ideal since there's actually more data posing the same problem. In simple terms I believe I'd like to pull all keys from this key vs all objects from this key, realizing there is a difference between objects and keys. I've worked around by creating a different data structure which is completely the wrong way to go about it. I'd like to learn the proper way for allKeys @key

Comment: Is the plist XML that you've posted the complete contents? If it is then its not in a valid format. Have you checked that `dict` contains anything at all?

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems quite a few things are wrong. My understanding of the plist structure and how to pull the data I want. I'll look into figuring out the proper way of implementing the structure and calls to retrieve the data desired